# How to easily manage adapters and/or decorators with runtime parameters?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I will give very simple example.

```
class Implementation: IMyInterface
{
    string mArg;

    public Implementation(string arg)
    {
        mArg = arg;
    }

    public DoStuff(object param)
    {
        // snip
    }
}

class Decorator: IMyInterface
{
    IMyInterface mWrapped;

    public Decorator(IMyInterface wrapped)
    {
        mWrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public DoStuff(object param)
    {
        var result = mWrapped.DoStuff(param);

        // snip

        return result;
    }
}
```

Now the argument I need for Implementation constructor I get from user in run-time.

```
IMyInterface GetMyObject()
{
    string arg = AskUserForString();

    return mContext.Resolve // HOW?
}
```

So what is the proper way to set this up and resolve to Decorated instance?

The example is simple. But imagine there are more layers (decorators/adapters) and the innermost implementation needs parameter I get in run-time.

Comment: Why not to write `return new Decorator(new Implementation(arg))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are using autofac, as it is in the tags of the question. 
You can try something along these lines:

```
public class ImplementationFactory
{
    private readonly IComponentContext container;

    public ImplementationFactory(IComponentContext container)
    {
        this.container = container;

    }
    public IMyInterface GetImplementation(string arg)
    {
        return container.Resolve<IMyInterface>(new NamedParameter("arg", arg));            
    }
}
```

And the registration/resolving part:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<ImplementationFactory>();
builder.RegisterType<Implementation>().Named<IMyInterface>("implementation");

builder.Register((c, args) => new Decorator(c.ResolveNamed<IMyInterface>("implementation", args.First())))
    .As<IMyInterface>();

var container = builder.Build();

var factory = container.Resolve<ImplementationFactory>();
var impl = factory.GetImplementation("abc"); //returns the decorator
```

If you have multiple decorators, you can chain them in the order you want within the registration:

```
builder.Register((c, args) => new Decorator(c.ResolveNamed<IMyInterface>("implementation", args.First())));
builder.Register((c, args) => new SecondDecorator(c.Resolve<Decorator>(args.First()))).As<IMyInterface>();
```

[Here is a good article about decorator support in autofac](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/decorator-support-in-autofac-2-4/) as well.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a factory object for the implementation and each of your decorators, and have the decorators' factories act like decorators to the implementation factory and just pass the input into the resolve call. Those you'd probably setup at application startup or in some configuration file.

To be very flexible, I would make a factory that takes a

```
Func<IMyInterface, IMyInterface>
```

or even a

```
Func<IMyInterface, string, IMyInterface>)
```

so it could build any kind of IMyInterface implmentation you want.

So something like this

```
interface IMyInterfaceFactory
{
   IMyInterface Resolve(string parameter);
}

class DecoratorFactory : IMyInterfaceFactory
{
   IMyInterfaceFactory parent;

   Func<IMyInterface, string, IMyInterface> resolver;

   public DecoratorFactory(
      IMyInterfaceFactory parent, 
      Func<IMyInterface, string, IMyInterface> resolver)
   {
      this.parent = parent;
      this.resolver= resolver;
   }

   public IMyInterface Resolve(string parameter)
   {
      var decoratee = parent.Resolve(parameter);

      return resolver(decoratee, parameter);
   }
}
```

And if you need more complex operations in the Resolve method, such as picking between multiple parents or resolver delegates, then you could just make another implementation of the factory interface for those.

Comment: oh, god, Factory for each decorator/adapter? I wouldn't call that easy.

Comment: Most of them probably can be just a single line of code to just make a Func that calls the Decorator's constructor, if using the above interface and class. The interesting bits are still just in the decorators themselves and how you compose the factories.

Comment: Good solution!  If you required this for different interfaces, you could use generics to set up the interface - so IMyInterfaceFactory<TEntity> would then replace occurrences IMyInterface and because you are using a function the factory doesn't need to know about the structure of the interface.  Overall though, this is the sort of solution you would be looking at!

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with just handing over the param to the interface.DoStuff method. Since the argument seems to be mandatory and is not a qualifier for a specific implementation of the interface you can just add another parameter to the DoStuff method.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I need it to load resources from disk, exactly once per instance.